# PowerShell Modify cmdlet in function

Tags: powershell, dynamic

I want to create a Function to run couple of cmdlets.

For Example:

```
Test-AcctDBConnection -DBConnection $CTXDBString
Test-AdminDBConnection -DBConnection $CTXDBString
```

All Commands are basicly the same. Just modified after `Test-$someParam`

I want to create a simple function like this

```
function CTX-Check {
    Param([string]$Check_Service)

    Write-Host $Check_Service
    try {
        Test-$Check_Service -DBConnection $CTXDBString
    } catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $_.Exception.Message
    }    
}
```

Some Ideas to solve this issue?  If I do the same with `Set-$someParam` that works fine.

Comment: I strongly advise to avoid this kind of meta-programming.

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers about avoiding this sort of thing in general - but if it's absolutely and conclusively unavoidable, you may find [`Get-Help -Command Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) to be of use.

Comment: I know that is not a "nice" structure of meta-programming. There are approx. 30 commands with the same structure. Anyone has a Idea to optimize it? Instead to duplicate the code?

Comment: If you're hell-bent on shooting yourself in the foot you could create a scriptblock from a command string and then invoke that scriptblock: `$s = "Test-${Check_Service} -DBConnection ${CTXDBString}"; $sb = [Scriptblock]::Create($s); & $sb`. Or use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). All caveats apply.

Comment: I know... I just want to avoid the bunch of code. I think about to retrive before all commands and use them. `$arrTestCommands = Get-Command Test-* | Where-Object {$_.Source -like "Citrix*"} | Select-Object Name` but there are a couple more commands than i need to check if the DB still connected or not. I using now the Invoke-Expression. Thats works fine. I dont tell anyone about that what i am doing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your commands take the same parameters, you can do something like this:

```
function Test-Citrix {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string]
        $Service,

        [string]
        $DBConnection
    )
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Service')

    foreach ($cmd in (Get-Command -Verb Test | ? Source -like Citrix*)) {
        & $cmd.Definition @PSBoundParameters
    }
}
```

Note: this will only work with functions, not cmdlets to my knowledge.  There are some extra steps involved there.